# Append or replace XML element based on attribute value using java

Tags: java, xml, xslt-3.0

I have two XML files of similar structure which I wish to merge into one file based on its attribute Id value. if Id value already exists, the code should replace other attributes else just append an element. Can you suggest which java XML parser library I can use?

So I would be grateful to anyone who gives me any sample example. Thanks in advance.

XML A:

```
<Returns>
   <Return Id="1001" MetadataFields="Code" MandatoryFields="Code1"/>
</Returns>
```

XML B:

```
<Returns>
   <Return Id="1000" MetadataFields="BankCode" MandatoryFields="BankCode"/>
   <Return Id="1001" MetadataFields="BankCode" MandatoryFields="BankCode1"/>
   <Return Id="1002" MetadataFields="BankCode" MandatoryFields="BankCode2"/>
   <Return Id="1003" MetadataFields="BankCode" MandatoryFields="BankCode3"/>
</Returns>
```

Output:

```
<Returns>
   <Return Id="1000" MetadataFields="BankCode" MandatoryFields="BankCode"/>
   <Return Id="1001" MetadataFields="Code" MandatoryFields="Code1"/>
   <Return Id="1002" MetadataFields="BankCode" MandatoryFields="BankCode2"/>
   <Return Id="1003" MetadataFields="BankCode" MandatoryFields="BankCode3"/>
</Returns>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3.0:

```
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
<Records>
  <xsl:merge>
    <xsl:merge-source for-each-source="doc('A.xml'), doc('B.xml')"
                  streamable="yes"
                  select="Returns/Return">
      <xsl:merge-key select="@Id" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:merge-source>
    <xsl:merge-action>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-merge-group()[last()]"/>
    <xsl:merge-action>
  </xsl:merge>
</Records>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please suggest me how to implement this in java code? I don't know much about XSLT

Comment: I sympathise, I often use the wrong tool for the job myself because I don't have time to learn how to use the right tool. But I'm not going to spend time teaching someone how to use the wrong tool!